# Switch to the another language on the same page?

Tags: middleman, middleman-4

I am trying to add a language changer for Middleman and it's not generating the correct link. My default and root is English.

```
url_for("/#{current_page.path}", locale: :ja)
```

I would expect the equivalent for the current page in JA which is the same URL with JA prepended. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a middleman beginner, but after doing a bunch of Googling it seems like this is a fairly common issue. I've tried to look through the middleman sources to see if I could find a solution, but I've been unable. I'm kinda disappointed about this, because it looks like middleman has first-class support for localizations. Being unable to easily link from one to another seems like a surprising omission.

What I've done is make a little helper that can swap localizations in paths, if needed.

```
def change_locale_in_path(path, locale)
  locale_prefix = I18n.locale

  path.gsub(/^#{locale_prefix}/, locale.to_s)
end
```

This isn't a great solution, though. It will need to be adjusted if you change the i18n `:path`, and won't work unless you `mount_at_root: false`. But, it worked well enough for me to move on. I really would love to see a better solution.

I found a few GitHub issues that seem to reference this problem. [Here's one](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/2189).

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following helper to generate a URL for the current page in a different language. It was originally based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/johnnyshields/98a695df51b1e99f3593579d3c9a3fd1), and then tweaked it a bit so that it works regardless of whether `mount_at_root` is used.

```
def current_url_for_locale(loc)
  url_regex = /\A\/(?:(#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')})\/)?/
  locale_root = url_for('/', locale: loc)
  current_page.url.gsub(url_regex, '').blank? ?
      locale_root :
      current_page.url.gsub(url_regex, locale_root)
end
```